# Android Databinding Compile Warning: Method references using '.' is deprecated

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I see the following compiler warning when building my project:

`warning: Method references using '.' is deprecated. Instead of 'item.onCardClicked', use 'item::onCardClicked'`

I am using android plugin for gradle 2.1.0.

My layout file looks like the following:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.example.Card"/>
</data>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:onClick="@{item.onCardClicked}"/>
...
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Can someone point me to the right direction to resolve this warning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37393655/212706

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per the error message:

> warning: Method references using '.' is deprecated. **Instead of 'item.onCardClicked', use 'item::onCardClicked'**

So replace `@{item.onCardClicked}` with `@{item::onCardClicked}`

Comment: The Android documentation on Android Databinding didn't mention anything about Java's method reference operator, so I was hesitant to adopt this. It seems that going forward, that will be the convention used. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that Android Studio might not support this notation so you might get red squigglies when editing the file.

Comment: Android Studio 2.1.3 didn't like the "::" notation in the layout editor (but still built the project). Android Studio 2.2.0 *still* doesn't like the "::" in the layout editor. ROFL !! I guess I'll use the dot notation in stead of :: because I hate to see error marks in a file - and I can psychologically ignore the gradle warnings easier.

Comment: Same in Android Studio 2.2.2. "::" shows as errors but the project builds and no build warnings. Tried to find the correct inspection in AS preferences, but there were none (at least as I could see...)