# Android Databinding: "Method references using '.' is deprecated"

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, data-binding, android-databinding

When using databinding in my app, I get the following warning when compiling:

`Warning:Method references using '.' is deprecated. Instead of 'handler.onItemClick', use 'handler::onItemClick'`

Please see my XML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable name="handler" type="ClickHandler"/>
        <variable name="active" type="boolean"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="@{!active ? handler.onItemClick : null}"
        android:background="@color/backgroundWhite"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

*Please note the **:** from the conditional statement*

Pretty straightforward message, until I change the '.' to '::'.

```
android:onClick="@{!active ? handler::onItemClick : null}"
```

Since the onItemClick is inside a conditional statement, it seems to interpret the first of the two ::'s as the 'else' statement of the condition. On the second ':', I get the error:

`<expr> expected, got ':'`

*EDIT: As @CommonsWare suggested in the comments, inverting the statement to
    `"@{active ? null : handler::onItemClick}"`
doesn't help either, a similar error is shown (see comments)*

*EDIT2: Apparently, when stripping the conditional statement away, being left with `"@{handler::onItemClick}"`, it still gives an error: `'!=', '%', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', <, <<, <=, '==', '>', '>=', '>>', '>>>' or '[' expected, got ':'` Using the dot-notation, still gives a warning when compiling*

**Is there any way to escape these ::'s, so it is interpreted correctly?**

Comment: In this case, you could try inverting the order as a workaround: `@{active ? null : handler::onItemClick}`. Otherwise, this feels like a bug in the data binding support.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Unfortunately, that also gives an error, on the first of the two ::'s this time:

`'!=', '%', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', <, <<, <=, '==', '>', '>=', '>>', '>>>' or '[' expected, got ':'`

Comment: Phooey. If you can create a sample project that demonstrates the error, you might [post a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list). I don't see one out there for this. I'll eventually try to reproduce this myself, if you don't get a chance to file an issue.

Comment: mine is perfectly working with this `android:onClick="@{active ? null : handler.onClicked}"` and there is no warning, i guess problem might be with class reference of handler.

Comment: @RRR: When using the '.', my project is also building/working, but with warnings that using method referencing with '.' is deprecated.

`Warning:Method references using '.' is deprecated.`

Comment: Yes that is what i am telling, i am not getting any warning. May i know which gradle version you are using?

Comment: Ah ok! Didn't catch that. I'm using Gradle plugin version 2.1.0.

Comment: Did you try parenthesis around `handler::onItemClick`?

Comment: Somehow, removing the whole condition, or adding parenthesis doesn't do anything. When using a '.', it is telling me to use the '::', when using the '::' it says it expected something else.

Comment: @Marcel50506 i seem to get the error as mentioned in edit2. What did you do to get rid of the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that the deprecation warning is shown because Android Data Binding is currently not being fully compatible with Java 8. 
Putting the following into your project's `build.gradle` file should hide mentioned warning.

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Unless you are using Java 8 features in your project.

Answer (score 3):

The '::' error is currently an open [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208917) for the Android Studio xml editor.

Comment: over 2 years old :)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to switch off Java 8 so I used the lambda expressions in databinding instead:

`android:onClick="@{(v)->handler.onItemClick(v)}"`

[Here](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-the-big-event-2697089dd0d7#.txt2y8u0m) is an article by George Mount that gives lots of examples.

One thing to note is that the lambda expression is bound when the event occurs not at binding time.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`.
Just use `app:onClick`, and define a BindingAdapter like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("onClick") 
public static void bindOnClick(View view, final Runnable runnable) {
    view.setOnClickListener(v -> runnable.run());
}
```

Then you can use `app:onClick="@{handler::onItemClick}"` without warnings or errors.